# Access Query Fields Out of Order

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ms-access-2007

My Access query is returning fields out of order.  It was my understanding that for each row from the query result the fields would be in the same order that were specified in the query's `SELECT` statement.  What am I doing wrong?

```
        String query =
            "SELECT " +
                "bas.[BAS BACnet Object Type/Instance], " +
                "bas.[BAS BACnet Object Name], " +
                "bas.[BAS Point List Description], " +
                "ore.[ORE Data Direction], " +
                "ref.[ENUM_H], " +
                "yk.[CCC Max Value (eng units)], " +
                "yk.[CCC Min Value (eng units)], " +
                "yk.[CCC Enum/Data Set], " +
                "ore.[ORE COV Increment], " +
                "ore.[ORE Display Precision] " +
            "FROM (([OV2 BAS] AS bas " +
            "INNER JOIN [OV2 ORE] AS ore ON bas.[Ref ID] = ore.[Ref ID]) " +
            "INNER JOIN [OV2 RefID] AS ref ON bas.[Ref ID] = ref.[Ref ID]) " +
            "INNER JOIN [YK CAPP] AS yk ON bas.[Ref ID] = yk.[Ref ID] " +
            "WHERE bas.[BAS BACnet Object Type/Instance] <> '';";

        try
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, this._conn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows == false)
            {
                Exception e = new Exception("Read of mapping table returned no results.");
                throw e;
            }

            while (reader.Read() != false)
            {
                Int32 columns;
                Object[] fields = new Object[10];

                columns = reader.GetValues(fields);

                avClass = new AVClass();

                for (int i = 0; i < AVClass.AV_CLASS_PROPERTIES; i++)
                {
                    avClass.Properties[i] = new AVProperty((AVProperty.PROPERTY_ID)i, fields[i]);
                    results.Add(avClass);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Not in the from but in the SELECT part of the query. And yes, they must be in that order, no exceptions.

Comment: @Svarog: Good catch!  I fixed the typo. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not clear whether it's the *only* problem, but this looks wrong to me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AVClass.AV_CLASS_PROPERTIES; i++)
{
    avClass.Properties[i] = new AVProperty((AVProperty.PROPERTY_ID)i, fields[i]);
    results.Add(avClass);
}
```

You're adding the same reference (`avClass`) to your results list *for every field*. I suspect you want to put that `Add` call *after* the loop.

Also, you haven't shown what `AVProperty.PROPERTY_ID` is, but you'd need make sure that the SELECT part of the query matches that. Presumably it's an enum... so you'd need the enum value corresponding to "bas.[BAS BACnet Object Type/Instance]" to have value 0, etc.

(If you can give more of the relevant code, we may be able to help you more. I'd also *strongly* recommend that you go through your code and make your names more self-explanatory and idiomatic. .NET doesn't use SHOUTY_CAPS for names.)

Additionally:

- You're not using `using` statements for any of the objects which should be disposed
- You're ignoring the value returned from `GetValues`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above they are in select order.

You are reading them in based on the ordering of avClass.Properties....
For this to work avXClass.Properties[3] must be where you want [Point List Description]

Not a good idea this change the ordering at either end and if you are lucky your code will fall over immediately.
Some sort of mapping might do it, or simply

AVClass.SetProperty[SomeKnownPropertyName] = reader.Fields[SomeKnownFieldName];